# NodeJS SOAP client request with certificate

Tags: node.js, soap, soap-client, client-certificates

I'm trying to connect to a SOAP service which requires a certificate on my NodeJS project.
I'm using [soap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap) and this is how I'm trying to access to it:

```
const soap = require('soap');
(...)

let sslOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(keyPath),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(certPath)
};
let sslHeaders = {
    Authorization: {
        user: 'Z100079',
        pass: password
    }
};
Service.GetLossRatio = function (contractID, start, end, asOf, cb) {
    process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
    let args = {
        contractID: contractID,
        start: start,
        end: end,
        asOf: asOf
    };
    soap.createClientAsync(url,
        {
            //request : specialRequest,
            wsdl_options: sslOptions,
            wsdl_headers: sslHeaders
        })
        .then((client) => {
            client.setSecurity(
                new soap.ClientSSLSecurityPFX(
                    certCerPath
                )
        );
        client.LossratioService.LossratioPort.calculate(args, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return cb(err);
            }
            console.log(res);
            return cb(null, res);
        });
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
        cb(e);
    });
};
```

And I'm getting a "Wrong Tag" Error when the LossratioPort.calculate() occurs.
I've no idea what that error means, I can't find much documentation about this specific situation, the "soap" documentation only show a brief explenation on how to make a request with certificates but there's not much more

I know the certificates are valid and I've tried with all the generated certificates from the .pem file (.p12, and .cer). I just want to be sure I'm getting something from the service. Either what I really want, or an error **from the server**, not from the api.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I'm able to get the service description thorugh client.describe() though:

{"LossratioService":{"LossratioPort":{"calculate":{"input":"tns:calculate","output":"tns:calculateResponse"},"ping":{"input":"tns:ping","output":"tns:pingResponse"},"shakedownTest":{"input":"tns:shakedownTest","output":"tns:shakedownTestResponse"}}}}

I've also confirmed the inputs, and I'm sending as the service requires.